# Reduzir tamanho de thumbs de alguns produtos no woocommerce/inserir produtos sem shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Tem uma loja virtual que exibe os produtos na home... produtos na categoria A e produtos na categoria B. Os da categoria A sao os principais, os da categoria B secundários. Então na home os thumbs dos produtos da categoria B tem que ser menores dos da categoria A. Preciso reduzi-los mas só sei reduzir de todos.

Fazendo isso sem colocar a mão no código acho que é impossível, não? Não achei nenhum plugin para isso.

Tentei usar o código abaixo, o inseri em uma página chamada loop-page no meu tema e não funcionou. Queria tentar inserir pelo código e assim ter uma maior liberdade com o html/css dos produtos. Com o shortcode, consegui organizar usando float:left, etc, mas se eu uso o width e height somente corta.

```
<?php 
$args = array(  
'post_type' => 'product',  
'meta_key' => '_featured',  
'meta_value' => 'yes',  
'posts_per_page' => 1  
);  

$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );  

if ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

while ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

    $featured_query->the_post();  

    $product = get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );  

    // Output product information here  

   endwhile;  

endif;  

wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset  ?>
```

Comment: E como é que você reduz todos os thumbs? Como você está diferenciando uma categoria de outra? Qual shortcode está usando? Porque seu código só puxa 1 produto por página? Como você está fazendo o `Output product information`?

Comment: Esse code foi um exemplo que inseri no arquivo da home do template que uso para tentar chamar os produtos ao inves da forma tradicional com shortcode, ali onde está 1 poderia ser outro valor, enfim mas nao funcionou. Eu estava usando [product_categories number=""], como tive que colocar os produtos em uma ordem especifica estou usando um por shortcode [product id="2243"]
[product id="2240"]
[product id="2234"]...  Para alterar o tamanho de todos é em Tools>Regen. Thumbnails

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro de tudo você precisa definir o tamanho da thumbnail diferente que você quer, no caso você deve usar [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) para faze isso.

Depois deve sobrescrever a função `woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail()`.

Por exemplo se a sua "Categoria B" tem o slug como `music` você pode fazer assim:

```php
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    global $post;

    $size = 'shop_catalog';

    if ( is_object_in_term( $post->ID, 'product_cat', 'music' ) ) {
        $size = 'thumbnail';
    }

    echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size );
}
```

Lembrando também de trocar `thumbnail` pelo slug do tamanho de imagem que você criou.

Por último deve subir a imagem novamente ou usar o [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) para recriar todas as imagens.